# How can I get this to print the new characters in a string properly in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, printing

Everytime I run this code, and I input something with the characters I want to be switched out with new characters, it only prints out the unchanged characters. What do I need to change to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"
int main()
{
 char originalPassword [50];
 char newPassword [50];
 int length;

printf("Please enter your current password. \n");
scanf("%s", originalPassword);
length = strlen(originalPassword);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", originalPassword[i]);
    if(originalPassword[i]=='i');
    {
       originalPassword[i] = '1';
    }
    
    if(originalPassword[i]=='a')
    {
       originalPassword[i]='@';
    }
    else
    {
        
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: You print *before* doing any switching. Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would have been useful to know.

Comment: "it only prints out the unchanged characters." Of course as code only prints with `printf("%c\n", originalPassword[i]);` before changing anything.

Comment: Writing `scanf("%s", ...);` is a catastrophe waiting to happen. At least write `scanf("%49s", ...);` to limit the characters read. If you learned that from a book, burn it. If you got it from an online tutorial, print it out  and burn it. And if you learned it from a tutor, well i don't condone burning humans at the stake, but at least tell him that someone on the internet disagrees with him.

Answer (score 1):

Should just have to move that printf statement in the for-loop to the bottom of the loop after the if-else statements and then it should print what you want.

For the future, if you're trying to print something and it's not printing what you want then try adding more printf statements in the code to see if the code gets to it. If they don't print then you know that it's not getting there.